# Why do I have to add a reference to URL/service.svc but then it creates a binding for URL/service.svc/soap?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, soap

I am connecting a solution to a WCF SOAP based web service. The URL is in the format:

> http://upload.pete.vls.com/api/hmlapi.svc

However when I add the reference the configuration comes up with the following:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://upload.pete.vls.com/api/HmlApi.svc/soap"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHmlApi"
                    contract="ServiceReference1.IHmlApi" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHmlApi" />
</client>
```

Im confused as to why when I add the reference with /soap/ on the end it doesnt work. But when I dont add it, the 'add reference' feature finds the service and adds it with a /soap/ anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are entering (without the `soap` part) includes information on what types of service transport are offered. VS is choosing `soap` from that, and saving the proper endpoint address in the config.

That end URL would *not* be correct for what is being asked for when you are prompted, though. Because it's expecting a URL with information on the service - not the actual endpoint that will eventually get used.

Answer (score 0):

Because your endpoint on the server is probably configured like that

```
<services>
  <service name="YourService">
    <endpoint name="mySOAPEndpoint" address="soap" binding="someHttpBinding" contract="IYourService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Note that the address is "soap" which is the relative path after your service URI (i.e. after the .svc). If you write address="" then your .svc URI is the same as your endpoint address.